# Ошибка 10013 Winsock при попытке создать широковещательный сокет

Tags: c++, winapi, сокет, winsock

Есть примитивная программа, которая должна одно сообщение постоянно спамить в эфир:

```
int main() {
setlocale(LC_ALL,"rus");

WSADATA wsaData;
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
    std::cerr << "Ошибка инициализации сокетов: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

// создание UDP сокета
SOCKET udpSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
if (udpSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    std::cerr << "Ошибка создания сокета: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// адрес и порт назначения
sockaddr_in destAddr;


destAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
destAddr.sin_port = htons(8564);
destAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_BROADCAST);

int i = 0;
// бесконечный цикл отправки сообщения
while (true) {
    
    i++;
    const char* message = "Test message № ";
    char buffer[1024];

    LPSTR errorMessage = NULL;
    int messageLength = std::strlen(buffer);
    std::sprintf(buffer, "%s%d", message, i);
    if (sendto(udpSocket,buffer, messageLength, 0, (sockaddr*)&destAddr, sizeof(destAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        DWORD errorCode = WSAGetLastError();
       
       FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM 
                      FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                      NULL, errorCode, 0, (LPSTR)&errorMessage, 0, NULL);
       std::cout << "Error: " << errorMessage << std::endl;
       closesocket(udpSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
  
    std::cout << buffer<<std::endl;
    Sleep(1000); // пауза в 1 секунду
}

closesocket(udpSocket);
WSACleanup();
return 0;
```

}

Пробовал другие порты указывать, отключил брандмауэр, среда от админа запущена. Что ему не нравится?

Comment: "отключил брандмауэр, среда от админа запущена" - а вот этого делать не следует

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед отправкой широковещательных сообщений сокету необходимо выставить опцию `SO_BROADCAST`:

```
BOOL const broadcast{TRUE};
if (SOCKET_ERROR == setsockopt(udpSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &broadcast, sizeof(broadcast)))
{
   // обработка ошибки
}
```

Перед использованием адрес необходимо инициализировать

```
sockaddr_in destAddr{};
```